# Firestore does not use sliding to delete Cell

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I can delete Cell and firestore using swipe.
But I want to realize that each cell has a button that can be clicked to delete, such as the picture[image]

This is my current code, I have tried for a long time and it is an error message
"Thread 1: "-[UIButton length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13111d4a0""Can anyone give me some advice? Thank you very much

This is my VC

```
class AiViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, SkeletonTableViewDataSource, CustomTvCellDelegate {

 func delete(didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        
        self.db.collection("Users").document(UID!).collection("AiBuyPost").document("\(String(describing: self.postArray[indexPath.row].postID))").delete { error in
            
            self.postArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.liveTableView.reloadData()
        }
        
    }

 func delete(didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        
        self.db.collection("Users").document(UID!).collection("AiBuyPost").document("\(String(describing: self.postArray[indexPath.row].postID))").delete { error in
            
            self.postArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.liveTableView.reloadData()
        }
        
    }
```

This is my Cell

```
 weak var delegate: CustomTvCellDelegate?

 @IBAction func deletebtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
      
        delegate?.delete(didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
        
        
        
    }
```

Comment: This is (a) not a Firestore issue and (b) not an ideal way to approach this. You should configure the cell prior to `cellForRowAt` instead of attempting to add a target to the cell's buttons in `cellForRowAt`, which is what is causing your error. Try doing all of the button configuration in the cell itself, ideally where you've subclassed it. You may want to create a delegate in the cell that is called when these buttons are pressed which would execute code in the view controller, such as the Firestore delete operation.

Comment: How should I call postArray[indexPath.row] in the cell?

Comment: I edited the question, help me to check if this is correct? Because the button still doesn't work.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Put a `print` statement inside the `deletebtn(_ sender: UIButton)` and `delete(didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` to first confirm it's all hooked up. Then, in the `cellForRowAt` method, which you've left out, do you set the cell delegate to `self`? Show that method.

Comment: I have successfully done it Thank you for your help